# DateTime reduce amount of months in C#

Tags: c#, oracle, datetime, plsql

I have a windows forms application and a database.

I got 2 fields where you can input your data.

In the second field you can put in months you want to reduce from today's date.

I want to make an oracle sql select to reduce the amount of months which was typed into the field.

Like:

```
SELECT * FROM <TABLE> WHERE <COLUMN> <= SYSTEM.DATETIME.TODAY - amount of months.
```

My problem is how can it calculate if its 01.09.2017 and I type in it should take 12 months so that the datetime get reduced with 12 months to 01.09.2016 ?

Comment: Why not do the calculation on the C# side?

Comment: C# `AddMonths(-12)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it in Oracle, you should use this-

```
ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -12)
```

But you can easily achieve the same in C# as well by doing this -

```
DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-12)
```

Comment: thans u helped me alot

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This is the **Oracle** solution:

```
add_months(sysdate, -12 )
```

Where `-12` is the number of months you're subtracting.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a negative number to `DateTime.AddMonths`:

```
DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-12); // 2016-09-01
```

Comment: thans u helped me alot

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to ORACLE 's [ADDMONTHS](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions004.htm#SQLRF00603) function.

Now given that you need to modify your query to something like

```
SELECT * FROM WHERE 'yourdatecolumn' <= ADD_MONTHS( CURRENT_DATE, 'noFromInoutField' )
```

Comment: thans u helped me alot

Comment: Glad to know it helped - if it did i would suggest you to up vote :)